# Swift: Adjust inputAccessoryView hight base on the subview UITextView Multiline

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, inputaccessoryview

I'm trying to adjust the `inputAccessoryView` height base on the `UITextView` inside the `inputAccessoryView` view just like iOS Native **Message App**. I'm able to adjust the hight of UITextView but can't make the `inputAccessoryView` to change the hight according to `UITextView` line. How is this possible in **Swift**?

**UITextView Hight Adjustment:**

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    var frame: CGRect  = MessageField.frame
    frame.size = MessageField.contentSize
    MessageField.frame = frame
}
```

I have read some QA in stack overflow but non of them seems to be working for me, I have tried the `autoresizingMask` *[Flexible Hight]*, [QA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816994/changing-the-frame-of-an-inputaccessoyview-in-ios-8), [QA2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983113/resizing-text-field-in-inputaccessoryview).

**Current Situation:** 
The UITextView resize hight, but not the input accessory.

**Screenshot:** 
[image]

Comment: Doesn't the `inputAccessoryView` get attached to the top of the pop-up keyboard, not the text field? Do you perhaps mean a `leftInputView` or `rightInputView` to show something *inside* the field?

Comment: Please see the screenshot, I have update the Question.  @NRitH

Comment: Do you mean the Send button, then? If so, and you're using constraints, then set a constraint between the text field and the Send button so that the `CenterY` constraint value is `0`.

Comment: No i mean the inputaccessoryview, you see how is behind the keyboard and not expending?

Comment: I need to figure out a way to change the constrain hight of the inputaccessoryview `constant` everytime a line is added in UITextView

Comment: OH, I see it now. I don't think that you need to adjust the *height* of the accessory view when the number of lines change, but instead you want to change the `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` to move the content up. The height of the accessory view is a separate problem. Give it an explicit size, and take its height into consideration when you adjust the `contentOffset` when the keyboard appears and disappears.

Comment: @NRitH can you show me that in code please?